# C# MD5 with RSA keystore

Tags: c#, security, md5, rsa

i need to create a Signature using a key store private keystore in C# .

The details of the Key Store is as follows:

```
   <certificate>
            <storeType>JKS</storeType>
            <storeName>classpath:docRtvKStoreS</storeName>
            <storePass>storexamp3</storePass>
            <keyPass>pass12rr</keyPass>
            <alias>rtvDocKeyRSA</alias>
            <algorithm>MD5WITHRSA</algorithm>
   </certificate
```

Does anyone of you know how to read the private keystore and use the certificate details to generate the signature in a C# application?

Example codes much appreciated.

Comment: Why md5? md5 isn't fit for signatures anymore.

Comment: Apparently a java keystore , JKS , cannot be opened using C# directly . Have found this link  http://teddyhai.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/how-to-convert-java-jks-keystore-to.html ... still looking for potential solutions .